# World of Warcraft Heirlooms for 'wrong' armor types

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm currently leveling a rogue with the benefit of heirlooms, and will pass the exp yielding armor on to my druid when he's done.

Will I be able to use this on a hunter, even though hunters wear mail instead of leather?

In a related note, would my wife's holy paladin be able to take advantage of the cloth or leather or mail heirlooms while leveling?

Comment: @McKay what is this worlf you speak of?

Comment: @antony.trupe heh, sorry.

Comment: One awesome stat on the leather heirlooms is the hit rating! I actually have both the leather and mail heirlooms on my alts, because the leather has hit, whereas the mail does not. It is very nice being able to swap between the two, because there are those times where the mobs are a level or two above you and that hit is invaluable. However, if you're killing mobs at your level then the mail is definitely better to wear because it has more agility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Longer Answer: Yes, you can use them as long as you have the necessary skill for the item (i.e. you can't wear the plate chest with your druid). The EXP-Bonus will work (tested this myself with my cloth wearing druid ;) ).

However, the stats on said items may not be exactly what you are looking for, but I guess this is really obvious. :)

Comment: I understand the stats won't be ideal. But I'll take them EMPTY and have the 10% bonus!! :-D Also I realize they're downgrade only. This makes me want to get cloth for casters and leather for melee/hunter. Glad to see you're speaking from experience, not theory. Thanks!

Comment: In the current case leather will do just fine on hunter. The pet will tank for the hunter anyway most of the time. just make sure to get the ash bow.

Comment: Also take into account that you will lose the Mail Specialization bonus when you get the Passive (sometime around L50). I know, a whole 5% down the drain! :p

Answer (score 3):

I bought only cloth heirlooms for this very reason: re-use on every alt I want. Sure you don't get the best stats or the passive bonuses once your level is high enough, but item stats aren't really *that* important during leveling, unlike the end-game.

Comment: very valid point. I hope it's still like this after cataclysm. - though this is not exactly an answer to the question. welcome to SE chain of sites. those are not forums. you'll get the jig of it eventually! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you select the "Mail" items at level 80, they automatically change between Mail/Leather if the character can train the appropriate skill at level 40.  Likewise with plate items.

Go for the proper gear if you can, the stats are better optimized, so in addition to more armor, you'll do more damage.

Comment: My goal is to minimize the number of heirlooms required, spending less time on my main farming badges. If I'm on my main farming, it's getting WG marks/SSK for honor to send to my alts, or getting ench mats. Alts, you see, are srsbsns.

Comment: If you do Argent Tournament dailies you will have enough Champion Seals to cover a full country, but that's just an option

Comment: This is correct. I've done the same thing with a hunter and shammy alt. I bought the mail heirlooms through the argent tournament, and was pleasantly surprised the first time that I sent them to my hunter and found that they'd been downgraded to leather so that I could wear them. Of course, upon hitting lvl 40 and training mail the items were upgraded to mail.